# kubuntu 20.04 keyboard shortcut issues

Tags: kubuntu, shortcuts

I just did a clean install of Kubuntu 20.04 after moving from 19.10 and have found some of the shortcuts not to be working.

In the system settings under Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts, I set the Audio Volume keys to the dedicated volume up/down keys on my keyboard. They get recognized in the settings but nothing happens to the audio when I press them.

I also have a key binding to open the System Settings window by pressing Meta+C which doesn't work either.

Comment: You may need to add info about your hardware.

Comment: I'm running this on a Dell XPS 13, but I don't see how hardware is an issue. I can assign the keys just fine in the system settings so they do get recognized

Comment: When I see "Audio Volume" I feel that the specific hardware may also make a difference, that is why I suggested it might be useful to also add info on the system where you have the issue.

Comment: ah ok, the volume itself works just fine when I change it using the slider in the applet. It's just the keyboard shortcuts that don't work